# Is it possible to disable apps without hiding them?

Tags: android, adb, app-manager, disable-app

### Background

End users can disable certain apps via the App manager which is built into the OS. This screen looks something like that (on some devices it says "Turn off" instead):

[image]

Once you disable an app, it will not be active and won't run in any way till you re-enable it again. However, in order to re-enable it, you can still find it on the app-manager, as shown [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-tos/325138-guide-how-disable-apps.html).

I'm trying to mimic this behavior on my "App Manager" app.

### What I tried

Using the ADB tool (or using root and then the ADB tool), you can use the next command to disable apps:

```
adb shell pm disable APP_PACKAGE_NAME
```

where "APP_PACKAGE_NAME" is the package name of the app to disable.

### The problem

If you use the ADB tool , the app you've chosen to disable will also get completely hidden from the app manager, even on the list of disabled apps.

### The question

Is there an alternative to disabling apps, that will not hide apps when disabling them?

If so, what is it?

Comment: Yes You can make your own launcher and Run a service to hide the app you want to

Comment: @SunilChaudhary Making my own launcher is not what I asked about. I asked if there is another, similar operation to disabling apps, that won't hide the apps. Anyway, this was a long time ago, and I don't think there is such an operation.